# Dynamically resize UICollectionView's supplementary view (containing multiline UILabel's)

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview

Inside a UICollectionView's supplementary view (header), I have a multiline label that I want to truncate to 3 lines.

[image]

When the user taps anywhere on the header (supplementary) view, I want to switch the UILabel to 0 lines so all text displays, and grow the collectionView's supplementary view's height accordingly (preferably animated). Here's what happens after you tap the header:

[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
// MyHeaderReusableView.m

// my gesture recognizer's action
- (IBAction)onHeaderTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    self.listIntro.numberOfLines = 0;

    // force -layoutSubviews to run again
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.listTitle.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.listTitle.frame.size.width;
    self.listIntro.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.listIntro.frame.size.width;
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [self systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    self.frame = ({
        CGRect headerFrame = self.frame;
        headerFrame.size.height = height;
        headerFrame;
    });

    NSLog(@"height: %@", @(height));
}
```

When I log `height` at the end of `layoutSubviews`, its value is 149 while the label is truncated and `numberOfLines` is set to 3. After tapping the headerView, setting `numberOfLines` to 0, and forcing a layout pass, height then gets recorded as 163.5. Great!

The only problem is that the entire headerView doesn't grow, and the cells don't get pushed down.

How can I dynamically change the height of my collectionView's supplementary view (preferably animated)?

I'm aware of UICollectionViewFlowLayout's `headerReferenceSize` and `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` but not quite sure how I'd use them in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

I got something working, but I'll admit, it feels kludgy. I feel like this could be accomplished with the standard CollectionView (and associated elements) API + hooking into standard layout/display invalidation, but I just couldn't get it working.

The only thing that would resize my headerView was setting my collection view's flow layout's `headerReferenceSize`. Unfortunately, I can't access my collection view or it's flow layout from my instance of UICollectionReusableView, so I had to create a delegate method to pass the correct height back.

Here's what I have now:

```
// in MyHeaderReusableView.m
//
// my UITapGestureRecognizer's action
- (IBAction)onHeaderTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    self.listIntro.numberOfLines = 0;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.listTitle.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.listTitle.frame.size.width;
    self.listIntro.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.listIntro.frame.size.width;

    CGFloat height = [self systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    self.frame = ({
        CGRect headerFrame = self.frame;
        headerFrame.size.height = height;
        headerFrame;
    });

    if (self.resizeDelegate) {
        [self.resizeDelegate wanderlistDetailHeaderDidResize:self.frame.size];
    }
}

// in my viewController subclass which owns the UICollectionView:
- (void)wanderlistDetailHeaderDidResize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

    // this is the key line
    flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = newSize;

    // this doesn't look beautiful but it's the best i can do for now. I would love for just the bottom of the frame to animate down, but instead, all the contents in the header (the top labels) have a crossfade effect applied.    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Like I said, not the solution I was looking for, but a working solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue than you, so I was just wondering: did you ever get a solution without the crossfade effect that you mention in the code sample?. My approach was pretty much the same, so I get the same problem. One additional comment though: I managed to implement the solution without the need for delegation: What I did was from "MyHeaderReusableView.m" You can reference the UICollectionView (and therefore, the UICollectionViewLayout) by:

```
//from MyHeaderReusableView.m
if ([self.superview isKindOfClass:UICollectionView.class]) {

    //get collectionView reference
    UICollectionView * collectionView = (UICollectionView*)self.superview;

    //layout
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout * layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    //... perform the header size change

}
```